# how to connect to db with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I updated my laravel4 to laravel5 now my problem is i cant connect to database

My mysql

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lue'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ' '),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

i returns this problem

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

help :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit your `.env` file in the root of your application and change the DB username and password there

Comment: i still get the same error  
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=lue
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD= 'mysql' => [
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
   'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lue'),
   'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
   'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ' '),
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
   'strict'    => false,
  ],

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the `.env` file, and not a `.env.php` file. In Laravel 4 there was a way to use `.env.environment.php` but in Laravel 5 it's all done with a `.env` file (note that it doesn't have a php suffix)

Also the data in the `.env` file must not be in the array format. It should just be as follows:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=longstring
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it.
Go to the root of your laravel folder (application folder) in my case it is `C:\firstapp` and open `.env` file in `notepad++` 
Update the following code accordingly.

```
DB_HOST=localhost 
DB_DATABASE=firstapp (this is database name)
DB_USERNAME=root (user name)
DB_PASSWORD= (password , leave empty if none , do not even put "")
```

**Important**
and then restart your application like this `php artisan serve` (using command line) while you are in the root of you application folder. See this image for clarification [link](http://prntscr.com/7r5j2t).

Comment: Should be php artisan serve :) Either way this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your .env file in the root of your application. Just configure as following example:

APP_ENV=local

APP_DEBUG=true

APP_KEY=6CqAQJdOd8oKoh0NhbefkmS0Pd8FDH6h

DB_HOST=localhost

DB_DATABASE=your database name

DB_USERNAME=your database user name

DB_PASSWORD=your password

CACHE_DRIVER=file

SESSION_DRIVER=file